# Why index of forEach is always 0 in array returned by IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection-observer

I am using the IntersectionObserver API.

When a specific section is entered, `background-color` is changed.
To handle this, I have to obtain the index of an entered entry in the array of `IntersectionObserverEntry` called `entries` here.

I used `forEach` method to get the index of the entry, but it strangely always set index as `0`. But when I access entry by obtained index, it works well.

```
const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach((entry,index) => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log('Intersecting',index);
      entry.target.className = entry.target.className.replace('hidden','fadeIn');
      changeBackgroundColor(entry.target.dataset.color);
      changeLogoColor(entry.target.dataset.theme);
    } else {
      console.log('Leave',index);
      entry.target.className = entry.target.className.replace('fadeIn','hidden');
    }
  });
});
const fadeInElemes = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
fadeInElemes.forEach((fadeInElem) => intersectionObserver.observe(fadeInElem));
```

Result is below...

> Intersecting 0
>   Leave 0
>   Leave 0 .....

What is wrong with my code? Why index is always 0, but access by obtained index results in the right element?

EDIT

[Log of entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW5bY.png)

Comment: IMHO the point of your issue isn't `indexOf()` behavior, try to log the array `entries`

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I edited for that.

Comment: Ok indexOf is failing because objects are shallow compared and returns only the first item found

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini At first, I suspected what you said, but if `indexOf` is not working, I cannot obtain right element for that index. However, it results in right element. Why?

Comment: Nope, try to iterate and log foreach second parama (Index), you probably do not need indexOf()

Comment: @MohanRamalingam with object comparison it may not work as expected

Comment: As you said, I even experimented second parameter of `forEach`, but failed for that too

Comment: Because entries array in callback of IntersectionObserver contain only one item and fadeInElemes are setting the observer N-times?
So each Intersecting 0, Leave 0, Leave 0 is called by fadeInElems foreach observe call

Comment: @dKorosec You are right, I figured out logging console. Anyway, thx for your comment

Comment: Can you set up a live example? From the [edit] mode, you should have access to what we call *StackSnippets* from the icon looking  like `<>`. We will need a bit of html, a bit of css and a bit of the logic to reproduce your case. But note that to have multiple *entries* in an IntersectionObserver callback, you'd need these elements to cross a threshold at the same exact time. Since here your thresholds are `[0]`, that would mean either they're at the same top position, or they meet at their top and bottom.

Comment: If `index` always is `0`, that just means that `entries.length` is always `1`.

Comment: @HaramBae Did you ever figure out why this is happening? Only way I could successfully index is setting ids of elements to index values and using if/switch statements on them.

Answer (score 3):

You can link index to element's property before register element in observer. **Important! Your property name should be unique to avoid overwriting standard properties.**

Please read comments below, i have separated the lines of code where the index has been saved (18 line) and readed (5 line).

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

        // read index from element’s property
        let index = entry.target.elems_index;

        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log(index, entry.target, 'is visible');
        } else {
            console.log(index, entry.target, 'is hidden');
        }
    })
});
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');
elems.forEach((elem, index) => {

    // save index as element’s property before register the element in observer
    elem.elems_index = index;

    observer.observe(elem);
});
```

Open pen's console there to see result there: https://codepen.io/rafaylik/pen/jOMQQdd

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the index of `entry` inside your forEach, no need to use indexOf().

```
entries.forEach((entry, i) => console.log(i))
```

The MDN web docs is well documented with nice exemples, you can most of the time find what you need there, [here is the link for the forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach)

Comment: Nope, I edited. It is not working. See my edited question

Comment: It's really work only first time on entrance to `forEach`. But deeper, inside the `entry.isIntersection` the `i` be 0 every time.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf may not work as you expect, when comparing objects:

```js
const user1 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
const user2 = {name : "nerd", org: "dev"};
const eq = user1 == user2;
console.log(eq); // gives false

const myArr = [user1, user2];
console.log(myArr.indexOf(user1)); // gives 0 because same instance
console.log(myArr.indexOf(user2)); // gives 1 because same instance

const myArr2 = [{name : "nerd", org: "dev"}, {name : "nerd", org: "dev"}];
console.log(myArr2.indexOf(user1)); // gives -1 because not same instance
console.log(myArr2.indexOf(user2)); // gives -1 because not same instance
```

If `IndexOf()` is returnig 0 it means current entry instance is the same as the one in position 0.

Take a look at how do you create your array, maybe entries contains the same instance across the array.

Comment: Even at [rev 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57286010/2) where they were indeed using indexOf, your answer wasn't making any sense. `forEach((el, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(el) === i)` will always only produce `true` if there is no duplicate entries, which is impossible in the callback of an IntersectionObserver

Comment: @Kaiido `Array.indexOf()` returns either *the index of the first found element* or *-1*. It do not returns a boolean, mate.

Comment: I refer to console.log('Leave',entries.indexOf(entry)), always returning 0

Comment: Because it always returns 0 in console.log, at every iteration

Comment: Mhaa... if it returns 0 its because it's been found, at index 0. So your answer saying that their object is not found because two object literals are not same objects is completely off. If you were somehow right, then they would have -1.

Answer (score 0):

you are logging the index from entries not from element array

```
fadeInElemes.forEach((fadeInElem) => intersectionObserver.observe(fadeInElem));
```

this is where you get the index you actually looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can check the entry target against the observed elements. So something like this:

```
const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.list-of-elements')

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  for(const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // compare target to element list
      const currentIndex = elementList.indexOf(entry.target)
    }
  }
})

Array.from(elementList).forEach(element => observer.observe(element))
```